# How to put a key as an argument

Tags: python, string, dictionary, arguments, method-call

I'm 
trying to put a key as an argument of this function, i just don't find how to do that :

```
city = {"Paris": 183, "Lyon": 220, "Marseille": 222 ,"Surfers Paradise": 475}

def plane_ride_cost(city): 
      for key, value in city():
         return value


print(plane_ride_cost("Marseille"))
```

I got this answer :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vion1/ele/Audric/TP 9.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(plane_ride_cost("Marseille"))
  File "C:/Users/vion1/ele/Audric/TP 9.py", line 9, in plane_ride_cost
    for key, value in city():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Thx for your help !

Comment: I wanna say thanks a lot for all these quick help, sorry for this beginner question, i searched A LOT before asking, but not in the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
city = {"Paris": 183, "Lyon": 220, "Marseille": 222 ,"Surfers Paradise": 475}

##define the parameter as the key
def plane_ride_cost(cityName): 
      return city[cityName] #return the value from dictionary using the key passed


print(plane_ride_cost("Marseille"))  #returns 222
```

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden the global `city` variable by using the same variable name as the argument for your function. Rename your global dictionary to something like `cities` and refer to that instead to avoid the collision and unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

No parentheses on `city` inside function `plane_ride_cost()`, because those are used for functions, and a string is not a function :)

```py
def plane_ride_cost(city): 
      for key, value in city.items(): #removed parentheses (was city())
         return value
```